# Error attempting to send mail with attachment using CFMail

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfmail

I am trying to send an email with an attached file to it but I am getting an error that I am not familiar with.

This is my code for the `<cfmail>` tag:

```
<CFMAIL FROM="test@test.com" TO="test2@test2.com"  SUBJECT="Test" type="HTML">
<P> This is the attachments test</P>
<p> For this test to be successful, we need to receive some file attachments with this email</p>
  <cfsilent>
    <cfloop query="result">

        <cfmailparam file="#result.NAME#" disposition="attachment">

    </cfloop>
  </cfsilent>
</cfmail>
```

And this is the error:

```
The resource 2011093475839213.txt was not found.

**The root cause was: ''.**

The error occurred in E:\sites\Example.Com\FolderExistsTest.cfm: line 71
69 :     <cfloop query="result">
70 :       
71 :         <cfmailparam file="#result.NAME#" disposition="attachment" type="text">
72 :     
73 :     </cfloop>
```

Please note that the file I am trying to attach does exist.

Comment: You are sending cfmailparam the name of the file (2011093475839213.txt).   Don't you have to specify a full path "C:\WebServerPath\Files\2011093475839213.txt"

Comment: I found the error and you are right.
This is the solution:      `<cfmailparam file="#CurrentDirectory#\#result.NAME#" disposition="attachment" type="text">`

Comment: If JMC provided the solution, he should post it as an answer so you can accept it

Comment: I found the solution before JMC posted his suggestion here but I would be more than happy to give him credit for the correct answer since he was on point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to specify the path for the file.

```
   <cfmailparam file="#CurrentDirectory#\#result.NAME#" disposition="attachment" type="text">
```

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" the answer to act as a signpost for future readers.

Comment: I have to wait until tomorrow to accept my own answer. I will make sure to mark it as accepted first thing tomorrow. Thanks